# Is there a way to fix an image 's position inside a div without background?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, css-position, background-position

I'm currently integrating an article's view in a ruby on rails environment.
I wanted to create a 450px height div set the article's image inside it and fix so it would look like this

```
<div class="image_container>
    <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" /> <!-- or <%= image_tag @article.image %> -->
</div>
```

and the css would look like this

```
.image_container{
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow-y: hidden
}

.image_contianer img{
 height: 100%
 position: fixed;
}
```

Obviously, it worked until I set the position to fixed, where it got fixed for the viewport and not the div.

Is there a way to fix it in a way or an other, without using `background-image` directly in the html to get the image fixed?

**EDIT**

I created a codepen so you guys can understand what I'm talking about, sorry for the time it took:

http://codepen.io/Drillan767/pen/rrKgyA

Thank you in advance

Comment: `position:absolute` ...not fixed...that should do it.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work, the image still follows the scroll

Comment: So you want the image to stay stationary? Isn't that exactly what `fixed` does?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want the image to scroll with you? Or do you just want it to sit inside the container?

Comment: I realize I badly asked my question: I'd like it to sit inside a div, and stay fixed, the same way as if you were using `background-position: fixed`, excepted that my image isn't called from a css file

Comment: can you set up a pen or fiddle, would be easier to try out quickly

Comment: I updated my question with a codepen

Comment: so why is `background-position: fixed;` out of the question, just curious?

Comment: I tried to use `background-position: fixed` on the image, but when I do so, the image gets back its width and height, and stay fixed in relation with the browser / viewport instead of the div containing it. that's why i'm looking for a solution where I don't have to put some `style` inside my HTML to put it as background-image

Comment: yeah, you could set `style="background-image: url(...)"` and have the rest of the CSS-rules in you `.css`-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have a solution where I nest `div`s to achieve the same effect:

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-container-holder {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.my-child {
  height: 40rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
  margin-top: 20rem;
  margin-left: 5rem;
}
```

-

```
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/1450/500">
  <div class="image-container-holder">
    <div class="my-child">
      Here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It solves it, although I would still say getting it to work with `background-position: fixed` would be a nicer solution.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkpKxY

Comment: I adapted your solution to my problem, and I'm pretty satisfied with the result after setting up some `overflow-y: hidden`, thank you!